# Unable to view google maps in released apk

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play, maps, google-maps-api-2

```
E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure. Please see 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how 
to correctly set up the map.
E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console 
(https://console.developers.google.com)</p>
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
```

I am getting the above error. The application works fine but i am unable to view the map in released version.
 I have checked the following points:

API key is correct

I couldn't find Google Maps Android API v2 but i have enabled Google Maps Android API

The debug apk works

I have created sha1 for release build

Please help

Comment: Is your package/sha1 combination correctly matching the ones in the console?

Comment: I ran cmd keytool to get my released apk sha1 and have used that in google maps api